# Should i create stack for package with extras?

Tags: ros, uav, mavlink

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some time ago i released base package, mavros.
Now i have additional package with extras. It require cv_bridge and absolutely optional.

Also i plan to do some rqt plugins for mavros, so it is another package.

Should i make stack from that packages? How to do it?
How to keep package naming?

Update: stacks are gone, but i mean same schema, when all packages stored in one repo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189676/should-i-create-stack-for-package-with-extras?/) by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 404 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using catkin: Stacks don't exist anymore. They have been replaced by [Metapackages](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages).

**Edit:**

Yes just do it. Put all packages in one repository and if you like add a Metapackage.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2014-08-11**:
Oh, yes i mean do metapackage, and place all those packages in one repo.